# Is there a grails plugin to create an online documentation guide?

Tags: plugins, grails, manuals

I am developing a grails app and was wondering if there is any grails plugin available to create online manuals in both HTML and PDF version, something like:

- Spring's reference docs which is hosted in both [html](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/index.html) and pdf versions.
- Yahoo! PlaceFinder [webservice guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/)

If there is not one available, can you please advise me on the tools that can be used to accomplish this.

The documentation is to be used by general public.

Comment: You wanna "automatically generate manuals" for your app? Anyway, I never see a plugin for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Grails documentation itself, and some Grails plugins uses GDoc for creating documentation in both html and pdf. Something worth taking a look at?

There is work in progress for new Groovy documentation using this infrastructure, see https://github.com/pledbrook/groovy-guide, you might take a look at build.gradle there to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This is what I was looking for.